# fullcalendar settings via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, calendar, fullcalendar

I would like to pass fullcalendar settings (i.e. startTime, endTime) via ajax. I would like to have something similar to this:

```
eventSources: 
[
"events.php",
"settings.php"
]
```

where events.php holds events array, settings.php holds settings array. If this approach works, how can i use settings values? If settings.php generates json: [{"minTime":"0","maxTime":"17"}], how to pass this settings to fullcalendar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at this:

http://www.feyasoft.com/myCalendar

"It is capable of rendering dynamic, calendar-style views of event data from JSON data"

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use a custom function instead to do something like this
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/
where you have a manual getJSON call, and strip out your settings data, and pass only the event data to the callback.

HOWEVER, fullcalendar's settings cannot yet be modified after the calendar loads, so this would be impossible. 
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=293

version 1.5 will likely have this "feature"